# Use range values as parameters in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc

I am connecting to a database via ODBC.  I have the SQL Statement written in VBA.  I have defined three parameters to pass, defined as cell references:

```
Dim Param1 As String
Dim Param2 As String
Dim Param3 As String

Param1 = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("P1").Value
Param2 = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("P2").Value`
Param3 = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("P3").Value
```

The between clause of the Where Statement works fine (Tables are examples) This is the end of the Statement:

```
(VPXXX.PDXXX Between " + Param1 + " and " + Param2 + "))"
```

When I try to add an "equal' Statement at the end, I throw an error "General ODBC Error:

```
AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX=" + Param3 + " ))"
```

Note: The Below end works

```
AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX='LDPDQ'))"
```

It just hard codes a single vendor

Hope this is enough info ..... First time building a query in SQL.  thanks in Advance

Comment: If `AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX='LDPDQ'))"` works, you probably need to add the quotation marks to `AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX=" + Param3 + " ))"`, i.e. `AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX='" + Param3 + "' ))"`, unless the quotation marks are already included in your cell value.  (P.S.  Why do you have two sets of `(  )`?  Not that it should affect things, but it shouldn't be needed either.)

Comment: 1) Thanks! I appreciate it.  I hate how simple it is sometimes :) 2) As for the double sets of "()" I have obviously been trained by the assistant to the assistant for the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: I'll put an "answer" in for the quotation marks (just so people don't keep looking at the question thinking it hasn't yet been solved), once I stop ROTFLMAO re your response about the double brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cell value itself isn't enclosed in single-quotation marks, you probably need to change

```
AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX=" + Param3 + " ))"
```

to include the quotation marks, i.e.

```
AND ((VPXXX.PDXXX='" + Param3 + "' ))"
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @YowE3K, you were missing `'` to enclose your values, so your code should be :

```
"VPXXX.PDXXX Between '" + Param1 + "' and '" + Param2 + "')"
```

and

```
"AND (VPXXX.PDXXX='" + Param3 + "')"
```

---

Btw, if you are using any `IN` statement in you SQL query, this could come in very handy :

```
Public Function ConcatSQL(RgToConcat As Range, Optional AllowMultipleS As Boolean = False) As String
Dim CelRg As Range
ConcatSQL = "('"
For Each CelRg In RgToConcat.Cells
    If CelRg.Value <> vbNullString And (InStr(1, ConcatSQL, CelRg.Value) = 0 Or AllowMultipleS) Then
        ConcatSQL = ConcatSQL & CelRg.Value & "', '"
    End If
Next CelRg
ConcatSQL = Left(ConcatSQL, Len(ConcatSQL) - 3) & ")"
End Function
```

How to use :

```
"VPXXX.PDXXX IN " & ConcatSQL(Sheets("SHEET1").Range("P1:P3"))
```